# What Supplements Should I Take When Restarting a New Exercise Plan?

Tags: supplements, energy-drinks

I spent about 6 to 7 years working out hard both in the gym and running, when I was in college.  When I graduated and got a job, I stopped working out cold turkey.  After about 3 years working, I realized I needed to get back into exercising regularly.

I've since since started working out again and weight more than ever.  I want to lose weight and gain muscle.

Should I take supplements that are all protein or should I take supplements that provide more carbohydrates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about supplements just yet, if you're only getting back into exercising now. They are intended to finesse results. The core of your plan should be healthy diet and exercise; you certainly don't need supplements to lose weight or to be healthy in general.

If you are going to pick between a focus on protein and carbohydrates I think that you're going to be better off with the protein. Protein is used to build up muscle and also helps suppress your appetite. Carbohydrates are extra energy, which you really don't need; certainly you'll pick some up in your diet (I'm not necessarily advocating for or against a very low-carb diet like Atkins - although it *will* work).

Comment: I just want to second this. People want the supplements to work for them but no supplement can replace what the core of exercise and nutrition will do. Get your baseline down, maybe add a quality multi-vitamin, then stick with it and save supplements for later tweaks.

Comment: and @Jeremy - Thank you both for your help!